# Compare cell with a previous one in the same column- VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have the data in excel like this, one column:

```
10/15/2021  7:59:42 AM
10/15/2021  7:59:44 AM
10/15/2021  7:59:46 AM
.
.
.
10/16/2021  7:59:42 AM
10/16/2021  7:59:48 AM
10/16/2021  7:59:49 AM
```

I used this code in VBA to create two columns, one with date and one with time:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = [A1]
    Set rng = Range(rng, Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

    rng.Texttocolumns Destination:=[B1], DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlMDYFormat), Array(2, xlMDYFormat), Array(3, xlGeneralFormat)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    
    Columns("C").Delete
    Columns("E").Delete
    Columns("D").Delete
    
End Sub
```

After that, I have two columns.
My goal is to have one column with date and time, but to have date only for the first time when it appears.
I have done this with excel using IF and later CONCAT.
I copied first row and for the second I used:

```
IF(B3=B2,"",B3)
```

The result is empty cell, I just then use CONCAT with row which contains time.
I would love to do this in VBA, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Most likely your dates are not Text strings, but rather real dates formatted to display the way you see. `TextToColumns` operates on the value in the cell, and not on the formatted display.  But Excel stores dates as a decimal number where the integer part represents the number of days since 1-Jan-1900, and the decimal part the fraction of the day (or time).  So you need to split accordingly into the integer and decimal parts of the value.

Comment: What you really want accomplishing? To eliminate the duplicated (identic) date? If so, you should use a single code line `rng.RemoveDuplicates 1`. Without `TextTocolumns` part...

Comment: I do not have any duplicate data, I have same date but different times. I separe them with texttocolumn, so I can apply IF and get date only first time when it appears, and in other cell I get empty, so when I use CONCAT, I have date +time only first time, and for other cells I have only time. I do this easily with if and concat, but I would like to do it with VBA

Comment: @RonRosenfeld everything is fine with TexttoColumns part, I get what I want, in one column date, in one column time. What I do after is important because I do it with IF and CONCAT, and I would like to do it with VBA.

Comment: Always faster to read the two columns into a VBA array (see [Arrays and Ranges in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)), then loop through it, blanking the appropriate entries; then write the array back to the worksheet.

Comment: So, do you need to keep only the first record (time) for a specific Date? If so, is the column in discussion formatted as Date or as Text?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, that is correct. As Date, Type *3/14/2012, and column with time: format -costum - h:mm:ss

Comment: Not that I wonted to know... The initial situation I meant: Is "10/15/2021  7:59:42 AM" formatted as date or as string. No need to firstly split by columns to accomplish what you need.

Comment: @FaneDuru The initial format is:  m/d/yyyy h:mm. I did split it because I had idea with IF and CONCAT.

Comment: So, the initial column is also Date formatted. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, correct.

Comment: It looks strange to me, since between the date and time there are two spaces. But, if you say so... I will prepare an answer. Not immediately, after I will finish something urgent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way. It will process the initial column, without splitting it by columns. It assumes that the column keeping the Date is "A:A". It should be very fast for larger ranges, using arrays and working in memory. It will return the processed array in column "B:B", starting from the second row (in the first one I assumed a header should be):

```
Sub keepFirstDateOnly_Date()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrD, arrFin
  Dim firstD As String, i As Long, j As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arrD = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value2
  ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrD), 1 To 1)
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrD)
     arrFin(i, 1) = Format(arrD(i, 1), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
     Do While DateSerial(Year(arrD(i + j, 1)), month(arrD(i + j, 1)), Day(arrD(i + j, 1))) = _
                              DateSerial(Year(arrD(i, 1)), month(arrD(i, 1)), Day(arrD(i, 1)))
        j = j + 1: If i + j >= UBound(arrD) Then Exit Do
        arrFin(i + j, 1) = Format(TimeValue(CDate(arrD(i + j, 1))), "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
     Loop
     i = i + j - 1: j = 0
  Next i
  sh.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

It works only if the range to be processed if formatted **As Date**, as you stated.

Please, test it and send some feedback.

The same suggestion to change "B2" with "A2" if you like the result in B:B, to make it overwriting the A:A existing content.

Comment: I tested, but this solution returns only the row where I have the date first time, so the result after the code is new column with 4 row because I have 4 different dates. But I need to keep every row, just not the date in every row.

Comment: @Ena So, you would like to keep what the above code shows, but on the row they exists initially?

Comment: So my data is like shown above, what I need as a result in one column is:

`1st row: 10/15/2021  7:59:42 

 2nd row: 7:59:44 

 3rd row: 7:59:46 
.
.
.

20th row: 10/16/2021  7:59:42
 
 21st row: 7:59:48 

 22nd row: 7:59:49`

The same row value as before, but the date is not shown every time, it is shown only when it appears first time.

Comment: OK. I will adapt it to return in that way. But I couldn't understand from your question what you really need, sorry...

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not explaining it in proper way.

Comment: @Ena But, didn't the updated code do what you need?

Comment: Nein, the result is same.

Comment: @Ena What does "the same" mean? Did you refresh the page (this one)? Please, test the updated code. But are you sure that the range to be processed is formatted as `Date`? If you select a cell from it and write the next code line, in a testing Sub `Debug.print Day(ActiveCell.Value)`, what does it return in Immediate Window?

Comment: When I use this the first edited code, I get the date when it is first time shown but without time, and the until next date, I have only time, which is good.

Comment: I am driving now...

Comment: @Ena `Format(arrD(i, 1), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")` should format it as necessary. You did not say anything about confirmation of Date format. If not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion? I would like to try adapting the code for its specificity. In my case, it works as it should.

Comment: I tried again in new excel, and it works. Thanks a lot!